# Encryption of big files in Java with AES/GCM

Tags: aes, file-encryption, gcm

I have to encrypt big files. Say their size ranges from 500mb to several of gigabytes.

I would like to use AES/GCM/NoPadding as provided by Java 1.8 since that gives me automatic authentication and encryption.

I would like to use the handy Cipher Input/Output Stream cause I can chain it with GZip I/O Streams to compress the data a little before encryption.

However I was reading that [the implementation of Java appends the authentication tag at the end of the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864440/aes-gcm-implementation-with-authentication-tag-in-java/26370130#26370130). That means that for a long file, if I were using CipherInputStream to decrypt it, it wont be able to tell whether the contents have been tampered or not until it reaches the end of the stream, right?

If that were the case, wouldn't it be problematic to actually use that operation mode for what I'm trying to accomplish becuase since the file can't be decrypted in memory it will have to be decrypted somewhere in the filesystem until the failure is detected, leaving some time for an attacker to see the plain text?

Is this a potential thread and a real concern that I should be worrying about or there's something about the algorithm / cipher streams that I'm missing and prevents that from ocurring?

Comment: In general it is better to ask runtime specific questions at stackoverflow. I've not voted to close as your actual question is not directly about the library. I've split my answer up in a theoretical and a Java specific part though (maybe other answers, if any, could do the same).

Comment: I'd stay away from the JDK CipherInputStream as it will silently eat any AEAD validation failures. See [JDK-8012900](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8012900) and [JDK-8016171](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016171). The JDK team know about this, but haven't been persuaded to change that behaviour (see [this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2014-March/010238.html)). Bouncy Castle has a more sane replacement implementation of CipherInputStream.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing in the GCM cipher that prevents it's use it in streaming mode. You should however not *use* the resulting plaintext during decryption for anything that requires security before you have verified the authentication tag.

The authentication tag is not to prevent you from decrypting the ciphertext. It is there to provide for integrity and authenticity. You should never decrypt where an attacker can see the plaintext. If possible, you should even try and make it hard for an attacker to perform side channel analysis.

Note that GCM is bounded to encrypting about 68 GB ($2^{39} - 256$ in bits) of data for a single IV. The amount of invocations is $2^{32}$ but you should be advised to stay well away from those limits. Note that repeating the IV for two separate encryption invocations is a catastrophic event for GCM.

---

`CipherInputStream` in general is horrible. I would suggest to reprogram it using `Cipher` and memory mapped files and `ByteBuffer` itself. The Java implementation (where the tag is automatically put at the end) and `CipherInputStream` make for this horrible buffering mess.

I'm rewriting the Bouncy Castle implementation and I see a code & complexity reduction of about 30% when I separate the tag from the decryption, plus it enables to decrypt each byte separately. In other words it restores the online properties of the underlying CTR cipher.

With Java 8 however you may want to stick to the Java 8 implementation as GCM may be sped up using intrinsics (for the server VM on the latest Intel processors). Note that according to archie below this functionality is not yet present.

Comment: Beware that the [tag size matters](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10775/practical-disadvantages-of-gcm-mode-encryption/10808#10808) with GCM. You could think of EAX or HMAC based authentication if you don't want to look into the security of GCM.

Comment: Bear in mind that the JDK 8 GCM implementation has crippled performance due to a naive (no HW or even tables) multiplier implementation. It also buffers plaintext during decryption in memory, so is unusable for large files. Hardware acceleration and/or other multiplier improvements are apparently in the works, but not there as of 1.8.0_25.

Comment: @archie Thanks for the warning. Note that you can always place the BC provider on top of the list of providers and have that take over, or make the provider configurable. I'll take another look at GCM as in Java 8, also because of a few updates regarding bugs with `CipherInputStream`. This is brand new functionality and is still a bit in movement.

Comment: @owlstead When you say that GCM is bound to ~68 GB, and that keys should be changed, my understanding is that it means to 68 GB in total, not necessarily on the same file. Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: @alejo I started to doubt myself and have looked up the requirements from NIST SP 800-38D and changed my answer accordingly. If unsure, look up the standard document.

Comment: @owlstead thanks, I started reading it a few hours

Comment: @alejo: ~68 GB per IV ... so basically it's a per file limitation since one should always use a new truly random IV per file

Comment: Regarding Java, with Java 9 Oracle modified Hotspot to use hardware acceleration on Intel CPUs.  The performance improvement is huge.

Comment: @Swashbuckler Do you mean *compared with Java 8* which already has AES intrinsics?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem which most software doesn't handle, surprisingly. Yes, decrypting to the filesystem is problematic as you guessed.

A better approach would be to split the file in "packets" and encrypt/authenticate each packet separately. However you will have to take care of many details (e.g. you can write only the first IV and implicitly increment it for the next packets; you will need to write the tag for each packet; and you will need to somehow mark the last packet using an e.g. additional data field in order to prevent an attacker from extending or truncating the ciphertext; there may be other steps I'm not aware of). Sadly I don't know any common/standard way to do this in order to guide implementors.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to figure out this for a while. All I had the impression (due to my lack of experience with that) that there were going to be issues (the ones I mention on my question). Unfortunately I'm confirming that there are many caveats like those you mention. That makes me wonder whether the approach I'm trying to use is the appropriate or what's the way you would tackle this issue instead

Answer (score 0):

Very late to answer this but smoke solution for this is just use cipher.final. I tested this and it is very fast 1GB I was able to decrypt in just 30 Sec

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));
byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(fileIn.readAllBytes());

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. This is asked almost 10 year ago where CPUs and SSDs are not common and the OP may have some limited platform in their mind ( not mentioned, yes some people cryptic about those). `cipher.final` just close the file and add the tag to the ciphertext and assoicated data if there is any. Nothing special about the OPs problem in mind.